# Spring And EventSource

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, eventsource

I 'm trying to send notification to my website.
My EventSource do NOT stay open. It closes and open indefinitely.
It doesn't stay open for seconds.

Javascript

```
this.subscribe = function(eid, cid) {
        if (!!window.EventSource) {
            //no authentication. Be carreful
            source = new EventSource(config.apiUrl + "v1/e/" + eid + "/c/" + cid + "/sse");
            source.onerror = error;
            source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
                console.log(e.data);
            }, false);

            source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
                // Connection was opened.
                console.log(e.data);
            }, false);

            source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
                if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
                    // Connection was closed.
                }
            }, false);
        } else {
            // Result to xhr polling :(
            console.log("No notifications available");
        }
    }
```

Java part

```
SseEmitter subscribeUpdates() {
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();
    synchronized (this.sseEmitters) {
        this.sseEmitters.add(sseEmitter);
        sseEmitter.onCompletion(() -> {
            synchronized (this.sseEmitters) {
                this.sseEmitters.remove(sseEmitter);
            }
        });
    }
    return sseEmitter;
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

---

Without any clue, I managed to do things differently.
I have a NodeJS server which supplies things like SSE, Websocket and others RealTime stuff. 
My Spring app juste send event to nodeJS which send it to clients.

Answer (score 0):

Send a message from JAVA with your chosen payload to indicate no more data :

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    if ('END-OF-STREAM' == e.data) {
        source.close(); // stop retry
    }
    console.log(e.data);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a timeout for the SseEmitter like that:
`SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter(300000L); // 5 min`